# Timed out waiting for device /dev/ttyNVT0

Tags: debian, systemd, console, serial-port

I want to make a physical remote serial port for my server that lets me use this port as a server serial console (this is for retro computer related hobby). I'm using a MikroTik router with its serial port being used as an RFC2217 server on the network. A Debian server uses ttynvt https://gitlab.com/lars-thrane-as/ttynvt to create a virtual serial port ttyNVT0 that represents a remote physical serial port on router. I can use this port with terminal emulator Minicom and it acts as a simple serial port on the server. Plugging in loopback plug on the router serial port returns typed data. It also works with python.
However, I'm unable to make this port work with agetty using a systemd. I'm following this manual:
https://www.rogerirwin.co.nz/linux-open-source/enabling-a-serial-port-console/
Of course, I've replaced ttyS0 with ttyNVT0. However, after issuing a command:

```
systemctl start serial-getty@ttyNVT0.service
```

It waits for some time and fails. journalctl -e shows this:

```
Nov 07 14:20:05 debian systemd[1]: dev-ttyNVT0.device: Job dev-ttyNVT0.device/start timed out.
Nov 07 14:20:05 debian systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device /dev/ttyNVT0.
Nov 07 14:20:05 debian systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Serial Getty on ttyNVT0.
Nov 07 14:20:05 debian systemd[1]: serial-getty@ttyNVT0.service: Job serial-getty@ttyNVT0.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Nov 07 14:20:05 debian systemd[1]: dev-ttyNVT0.device: Job dev-ttyNVT0.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
```

I tried the same with local serial port ttyS0 and it works without any problems.

I'm sorry if I'm missing something obvious here, but I have no big experience with systemd and I don't really know where to look to fix this.

I tried the same systemd service with serial port ttyS0 and it works. Tried rebooting. I don't really know what to try because I don't really know what "Timed out waiting for device" means. I mean - it's there, it works with minicom, why don't it work with systemd?
I also tried to simply run agetty on ttyNVT0 interface with command:

```
/sbin/agetty --local-line 9600 ttyNVT0 vt100
```

and it actually works, I can login into server from remote serial port.